# Workflow Bookmark Issue

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

WF Tasks - T1 > T2 > T3
Steps

1 * Workflow Instance is started & bookmarked at first task T1
2 * Trying to Load the workflow Instance,Instance starts successfully and moves to next task,
    but bookmark information is not getting updated to 
    [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancesTable] 
    it shows the old book marked information only

I tried tracing the workflow its coming to bookmark stage and sending bookmark information of next task T2 in the code activity of bookmark and  context.CreateBookmark(bookmarkName,new BookmarkCallback(OnReadComplete)); is called but its not updating the the instance information with new bookmark..

Answer (score 2):

The workflow persistence database is not updated until the workflow persist again. That is by design so you can restart from a known point if you application crashes. You can force persistence by adding Persist activities to your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Adding with "The problem solver" answer you can refer for persistance points.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489420.aspx